# how to show the negative number factorial in this code

Tags: java, string, algorithm, math, biginteger

im trying to make a calculator and im was unable to continue because of some confusion in my codes. i was trying to make a factorial of a number, if its a positive number there is no error but every time i input a negative number it results to 1, here is my code .

```
 import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial2 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
       int n = s.nextInt();
       String fact = factorial(n);
       System.out.println("Factorial is " + fact);
   }

   public static String factorial(int n) {
       BigInteger fact = new BigInteger("1");
       for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
           fact = fact.multiply(new BigInteger(i + ""));
       }
       return fact.toString();
   }
}
```

i already tried making if statements but still it results to 1.i also want to make the negative factorial into a display text not the value of the negative factorial

Comment: There is nothing like *negative* factorial.

Comment: Not ***directly*** to your question; but `BigInteger fact = BigInteger.ONE;` and `fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));`

Comment: like i need the gamma operation, like in the scientific calculator that if you input a negative number you can have its factorial

Comment: On factorial of negative numbers: [Factorials of real negative and imaginary numbers - A new perspective](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4247832/). Quote: “In 1768, Euler defined the gamma function, Γ(z), and extended the concept of factorials to all real negative numbers, except zero and negative integers.”

Comment: Alternatively, if you want us to tell you how to compute negative factorials, you need to provide us with a definition of what a negative factorial is ... in clear mathematical terms.

Comment: *"... like in the scientific calculator that if you input a negative number you can have its factorial"*  - My calculator says "Error".

Comment: So does the Google calculator, provided that you input it correctly; i.e. `(-7)!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to validate the input before the calculation, example:

```
public static String factorial(int n) {
    if(n < 1) return "0";
    BigInteger fact = new BigInteger("1");
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fact = fact.multiply(new BigInteger(i + ""));
    }
    return fact.toString();
}
```

Of course you can define any default return value or throw an error:

```
if(n < 1) throw new RuntimeException("Input must be > 0");
```

Comment: what if i want to return the real value of negative number factorial? what should i add in the return statement?

Comment: As per definition from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Definition it applies only for integers >= 0, I don't know, what you want to do